# The problem is threefold?

Tags: numbers, suffixes

> The problems ***are*** threefold.
>   The problem ***is*** threefold.

Which is the right way to use the -fold suffix?

---

*Note - This question was previously asked by [a user whose account has been suspended](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/23135/nortonn-s), so the question was auto-deleted. I'm re-posting now it because I think this is a valid question.*

Comment: According to Waiwai, this question was plagiarized--you might want to pull up the attribution

Comment: Who cares where it comes from? Has anybody noticed yet that there's a metaphor of _folding_ involved? Things that are folded are separated in one sense and connected in another. That doesn't sit well with binary Singular/Plural.

Comment: @JohnLawler I didn't say delete it, I said to consider giving the original post credit. Another user was [suspended for this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2742/10893)

Comment: Alas, I have no knowledge of almost all individual users, and less interest in internal politics.

Comment: @John Lawler: Until I just read your comment, I hadn't even registered the metaphoric element. Not for the first time, I must admit - you're obviously more used to being consciously aware of metaphoric usage than most of us. But that certainly accords with my default assumption that *threefold* implies *one thing with three aspects*, more often than *three things*.

Comment: @simchona: I'm not sure if you mean plagiarised by *me*, or plagiarised by *[suspended user] Nortonn S*. Whatever - I've added a link to his profile if that's what you want. Though looking at the profile a little closer, I see the suspension is only for a month (the only other one I've seen was for *three years*). So arguably it's a bit mean to publicise the situation too much. Perhaps the appropriate etiquette should be explored a bit on meta.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: simchona means "plagiarized by the suspended user"; (s)he's referring to waiwai933's answer to your question on meta, which explained the deletion of the original question as being because it "was plagiarized from another online forum."

Comment: @ruakh: Ooo-er, missus! Does that mean **I** can expect to have my ELU account suspended for plagiarising a plagiarised question? I think that's way ott - many questions posed here have already arisen elsewhere, as I've often discovered on Googling the exact text of a question, and ending up on a YahooAnswers page.

Comment: [My troubles are ninety-ninefold, yet a female dog is not among them.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14it95LOuxw) - Jay-Z

Comment: @MT_Head: I quite like that track, so I knew before I checked that Jay-Z definitely wouldn't have said *"ninety-ninefold"*. Actually, I wouldn't have expected *anyone* to come out with such an ugly construction other than whimsically, but [24,900 Google hits says I was wrong on that score](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22ninety-nine+fold%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - How about "We seek a penalty fiftyfold for General Stanley's story..."

Comment: @MT_Head: Sure - *fiftyfold*, even *two hundredfold*, or *five thousandfold*. But *ninety-ninefold*? That level of precision is for accountants and academics, not everyday life and language.

Answer (score 7):

The actual question does not seem to quite compare like with like due to pluralization, e.g.

**The problems are threefold.**
  Could seem to - possibly - mean multiple problems have 3 parts to each of them.

**The problem is threefold.**
  One problem has three parts.  Definitely just One problem (but with 3 parts).

The *is* and *are* are getting used based on the pluralization of problem, after all one can't have "problem are" or "problems is".

In practice both forms are basically **usually** used to mean the same thing, 3 parts to one thing.

Comment: I have a problem with this question, and that problem is twofold. First, the question was already deleted, so why is it being reintroduced? Second, the title says "twofold," but the example sentences say "threefold" – that's inconsistent. (Truth be told, I don't have _any_ problem with this question; I just made all that up to test Michael's postulate. It seems to work just fine, so I'll upvote his answer.)

Answer (score 5):

If I heard someone speak your first sentence, I would assume that there is a *set* of problems, and that *each problem in that set* is threefold. If I heard the second, I would assume that there is a *single* problem, and that this problem is threefold.

Comment: I feel like something of a "fifth columnist" here, in that [I didn't actually ask this question in the first place](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/). But I agree grammatically that's a possible interpretation, per the final paragraph in my own answer. Semantically I feel it's less likely than the other two interpretations, but sadly we can no longer ask the *original* OP for his exact context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much light it sheds on current use, but I'm fairly sure the origin of the phrase was from physical craftsmanship.  Leather, for example, folded over itself several times, is stronger than a block of the same depth.  You can apparently do the same with metal; *threefold bronze* was a Roman metaphor for strength. [*Aes triplex* in Latin; the English word *complex/complicate* is from a similar root.]

Comment: OED acknowledges the physical folding/pleating sense of words with the *-fold* suffix, but says they *"serve also **and chiefly** as arithmetical multiplicatives"*. OED also say the "multiplied by" sense applied to ancient Greek & Latin equivalents, and the Teutonic precursor to English *-fold*, so I'm not sure I'd agree *"the origin of the phrase was from physical craftsmanship"*.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms occur - but for what it's worth, ["is threefold" is more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20threefold,are%20threefold&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image]

The difference is simply one of style/emphasis. The *problem **is** threefold* if you see it as a single problem with three "sub-components", or "aspects". If you think there are actually three distinct problems, you might feasibly say the *problems **are** threefold* - but I think this is clumsy phrasing, and would be better expressed by saying *there are three problems*.

Personally I think that when something - singular *or* plural - is described as *threefold*, this usually implies there are *three aspects relating to one thing or group of things*. Thus a third interpretation is possible, whereby *the problems are threefold* could refer to any number of problems, all of which share three particular characteristics.

Comment: *The problems are threefold* for "There are three problems" is probably archaic (or pseudo-archaic), but not really clumsy.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Well, the fact that my NGram shows a significant bias towards *"**is** threefold"* does rather suggest that most usages are in the context of a single thing [problem, whatever] having three aspects. And since that's my "default" understanding of how the word is used, anything that conflicts with it is "clumsy". I doubt it's really "archaic" though, since the plural form [got started much later than the singular](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+threefold%2Care+threefold&year_start=1700&year_end=1800&corpus=0&smoothing=3) ("pseudo-archaic" is possible though).