# Correct usage of word "reason" with "twofold"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I want to say that there were two reasons for something. Which would be grammatically correct?

"The reason for this is twofold" or "The reasons for this are twofold"

Or is it that both of these are technically correct but mean separate things? Do they both mean the same thing but one is preferred over the other?

Thanks for you help

Comment: twofold /ˈtuːˌfoʊld/  adjective
Learner's definition of TWOFOLD
1 
: twice as much or as many
a twofold increase in spending
2 
: having two parts
The aims of the study are twofold.
— twofold /ˈtuːˈfoʊld/  adverb
Our funding increased twofold last year.

Comment: I think I get it now. It would be better to use singular reason when the two reasons can somehow be combined to make up a whole. Likewise, plural reasons should be used when the two are discrete and better left separate

Comment: There is some discussion on this topic [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72089/the-problem-is-threefold).

Answer (score 6):

How about: "The reason is twofold." By saying that the reason is twofold, it means that there are two parts to the same reason, not that there are two separate reasons. If you wanted to say that there are two separate reasons for a phenomenon, then I would simply say: "There are two reasons for this occurrence," or something along those lines.

Comment: Please cite published evidence (e.g. dictionary definition) to support your explanation. See also [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Comment: Collins supports your reply.